# ember normalizeResponse when navigated to page from link-to

Tags: javascript, ember.js, metadata, link-to, serialization

When I navigate to a specific page, the overridden function `normalizeResponse` in my serializer used in conjunction with code in my router `model` function, to add meta data to my model, works correctly.  Basically, `normalizeResponse` runs first, then my `model` function in my router.

`serializers/application.js`

```
import App from '../app';
import JSONAPISerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json-api';

App.storeMeta = {};

export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload){
    App.storeMeta[primaryModelClass.modelName] = payload.meta;
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

And in my model.

```
import App from '../app'
...
model(params){
  const data = {};

  return this.store.findRecord('myModelType', params.id).then((myModelType)=>{
    myModelType.meta = App.storeMeta['myModelType'];
    return myModelType;
  },()=>{ //error
    this.get('session').invalidate();
  });
}
```

When I navigate to that specific page through a `link-to` from another page, the model code gets called first, so there is no meta data being attached to the model.

How do I get the `normalizeResponse` function to run before the `model` function when navigated to from `link-to`?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, this seems like a issue that has been going on for years.  Is the work around to just do an ajax call and push to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for anyone who sees this is to add `{reload: true}` as a param to the  `findRecord` function.

So the second code snippet from my original post would know look like the following:

```
import App from '../app'
...
model(params){
  const data = {};

  return this.store.findRecord('myModelType', params.id, {reload: true}).then((myModelType)=>{
    myModelType.meta = App.storeMeta['myModelType'];
    return myModelType;
  },()=>{ //error
    this.get('session').invalidate();
  });
}
```

More info [here](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/da277635d1-force-ember-data-to-skip-cache-with-reload-true).  Thanks to that site for the answer.